# How to access Unvalidated Value in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have used:

`Request.Unvalidated.Form["valuefromcontrol"];`

Because my control returns values in tags, i.e (`<p> values </p>`) etc. but it gives `null` values.

I have searched about it and found this [Asp Unvalidated Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx)

But when I used the technique that is mentioned in above link it gives error
in the given link the description of Unvalidated Method is used as

```
string var = Request.Unvalidated("valueofcontrol");
```

and

```
string var = Request.Unvalidated().Form["valueofcontrol"];
```

But when I tried to use these technique vs gives an error saying that Unvalidated cannot used as method.

What should I do for getting value without validation ?

for more better understanding I have used CKEDITOR as a control.

Comment: `Request.Unvalidated.Form["nameOfControl"];` (`Unvalidated` is a property of `Request`, not a method). But why not use bind to a property with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute?

Comment: Thank you , i just solved it .

Comment: you can see my answer below to avoid this type of errors

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem using ValidateRequest=false; in aspx code file ..!

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true"  Inherits="admin_add_announcement" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

and on cs file i just used

```
string val = Request.Unvalidated.Form["controlname"];
```

it returns the controls value.